# Делаю телеграмм бота на python по telebot. В данном ниже коде, когда я нажимаю на кнопку в боте, то в ответ почему-то тишина

Tags: python, telebot

Ситуация:
Когда данный бот выводит сообщение с кнопкой о продаже, то нажимая на неё вижу 0 реакции от бота.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки бот выводил сообщение о запросе имени и сохранял указанное пользователем значение в глобальную переменную.

````
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "/start":
        begin = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        sell = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Продать товар", callback_data="sell")
        begin.add(sell)
        @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
        def beginning(call):
           ```@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
            def get_name(message): 
                if call.data == "sell":          
                    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введите название вашего товара")
                    global name
                    name = message.text
                    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, name, "Введите цену вашего товара")
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)```
````

После второго "@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])" начинаются неполадки

Comment: где ж вас учат хэндлеры засовывать в тело другого хэндлера?...

Comment: Я начинающий + самоучка) пытался и без хендлера - та же проблема

Comment: через глобальные переменные не самый лучший вариант, так как если ботом будут пользоваться 2 и более пользователя одновременно, то они попросту будут перезаписывать эти переменные. Вам нужно смотреть в сторону FSM (машины состояний)

Answer (score 0):

(content_types=['text']) перехватывает все введные собщения может по этому и остальные не работают.
по пробуйте заменить на @bot.message_handler(commands=['start']) и убрать if message.text == "/start":